# nullpointerexception when using redirection to file

Tags: java, file, redirect, nullpointerexception, console

So i have this Java code:

```
class Main{ 
    static String []htmlPage={"<html>","<head>","<title>","titleContent","</title>","</head>","<body>","bodyContent","</body>","</html>"};
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("<!--Enter title-->");
        String titleContent = System.console().readLine();
        System.out.println("<!--Enter body-->");
        String bodyContent = System.console().readLine();
        getHtmlPage(titleContent, bodyContent);
    }
    static void getHtmlPage( String titleContent,String bodyContent){
        String genPage="";
        for(String t: htmlPage){
            if(t.equals("titleContent")){t=titleContent;}
            if(t.equals("bodyContent")){t=bodyContent;}
            genPage+=t;
        }
        System.out.println(genPage);
    }   
}
```

Everything works fine, but when i want to redirect output to file (using >) - i get `NullPointerExcption`. Example:

```
java Main.java (runs great and everything OK)
java Main.java > genPage.html (NullPointer)
```

What is the way to fix this? Every ways is suitable, **but only static meths are allowed to use (without creating new obj)** Inside String []htmlPage - is basig HTML tag structure of web page

> (html,head,title,/title,/head,.....,/html)

Answer (score 0):

avoid using System.console and try this instead

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter String");
String s = br.readLine();
System.out.print("Enter Integer:");
```

so if you really need to use System.console(), read [this solution](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.ie/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html)

Comment: And why does it throws NullPointerException? I just want to use System.console(), but i got no ideas why  NullPointerException is generated and what is the case for this to occure?

Comment: I tried running your code both from IDE and bash. It gave same NullPointerException in both cases. I just modified your code as per my recommendation above and it worked fine. which java version are you using? which specific use case are you targeting where you have use System.console. This is not recommended practice.

Comment: You see? I know how to properly hold input and etc., but i need to study students, and i need to use some simple statements to show them some basic ideas of programming, so using obj - is not in my plans for the first lecture. That why i need only static meths. So are there no simple solution for such trivial task in Java?

Comment: Looks like I got the answer, you have to run this through standard linux shell or through cmd.exe in windows. I tried it and worked perfectly. The method System.console() can return null if there is no console device present. This wont even run through IDE. infact to my surprise I tried to run it through "git bash" in windows and it failed to associate that console with jvm. Now we know that it has to be system's standard console with proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to catch **unchecked expectations** (Like null pointer exceptions) via try and catch block, and try to print out the error stack trace to be able to identify where it throws the exception. also it's not recommended to use

```
System.console().readLine();
```

instead use

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputStream = sc.next();
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Main.main(Main.java:6)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Main.main(Main.java:12)

Comment: I can't identify line 6 or 12 in your code since it's not numbered.

Comment: I will repeat myself - System.console().readLine() - are the source for NullP.. exception. When code is started from console (cmd in my case), with command (java Main) - everything works great, BUT when i trying to redirect output to file, using (java Main > some.html) NullP.. appears. Besides this, output file is actualy generated,but without expected user nput which was lost due to System.console().readLine() NullP.. exc..